# Matching pattern span multiple line and remove those matching lines

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I was trying to use sed to do the following:

In file looks something like:

```
 FirstLine
 SecondLineEEE
 AAAblablabla
 ForthLineEEE
 FifthLine
 LastLine
```

I want to remove EEE (but keep the rest of second line) and the whole line starting with AAA and keep other part of the file intact.

The expected result is (as seen, if the following line doesn't start with AAA, it will be kept, that's why I need to match multiple lines.)

```
 FirstLine
 SecondLine
 ForthLineEEE
 FifthLine
 LastLine
```

How should I do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "FirstLine\nSecondLineEEE\nAAAblablabla\nLastLine" |
sed '/EEE$/{N;s/EEE\nAAA.*//}'
FirstLine
SecondLine
LastLine
```

Comment: Yes, this works for the sample case! However, in my real case, EEE is actually &, I tried \& and "&", doesn't seem to be able to match it. Any idea?

Comment: If I substitute `&` or `\&` for `EEE` I still match, perhaps there is something else at the end of line. Try `\&\s*\n\s*AAA` or use the `l` command following the `N` command i.e. `N;l`s/\&\s*\n\s*AAA.*//` good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
fge@erwin ~ $ sed '/EEE$/d; /^AAA/d' <<EOF
> FirstLine
> SecondLineEEE
> AAAblablabla
> LastLine
> EOF
FirstLine
LastLine
```

`/re/d` will remove all lines from the input matching regex `re`. Adapt the patterns to your needs.

Comment: Sorry, actually I want to keep the rest of the second line. But I will try to change your command myself.

Answer (score 1):

May be this could work -

```
sed '/EEE$/N;s/\(.*\)EEE\nAAA.*/\1/' filename
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
FirstLine
SecondLineEEE
AAAblablabla
ForthLineEEE
FifthLine
LastLine

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed '/EEE$/N;s/\(.*\)EEE\nAAA.*/\1/' file
FirstLine
SecondLine
ForthLineEEE
FifthLine
LastLine
```