# sed insert multiple lines before multiple lines pattern

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I have the following very long file:

```
...
close unit 1
...
...
close unit 1
...
...
close unit 1

stop
```

I want to insert multiples lines before the last `close unit 1` which is before `stop`. The file contains an undefined number of `close unit 1`.

I found a lot of other similar questions here and there, but the answers couldn't help me... For example I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/8635732/1689664 but this didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` and `tac`:

```
$ tac inputfile | sed '/close unit 1/ {s/\(.*\)/\1\nLine3\nLine2\nLine1/; :loop; n; b loop}' | tac
...
close unit 1
...
...
close unit 1
...
...
Line1
Line2
Line3
close unit 1

stop
```

Note that you'd need to specify the input *lines* in the reverse order in the `sed` expression.

Comment: Hmmm, sometimes I don't get any output... Did you ever experienced that?

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker Can you post an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: This will produce 0 byte files from time to time:
    for i in *
    do
    tac $i | sed '/close unit 1/ {s/\(.*\)/\1\nLine3\nLine2\nLine1/; :loop; n; b loop}' | tac | tee $i
    done

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '  push @arr, $_;
            print shift @arr if @arr > 3;
            if ("stop\n" eq $_ and "close unit 1\n" eq $arr[0]) {
                print "\n\n";                                     # Inserted lines
            }
         }{ print @arr ' long-file > new-file
```

It keeps a sliding window of last 3 lines, if the last line in the window is `stop` and the first one is `close unit 1`, it prints the lines.

Another possibility is to use `nl` to number the lines, then `grep` lines containing `close unit 1`, getting the number of the last such a line and using it in a `sed` address:

```
nl -ba long-file \
    | grep -F 'close unit 1' \
    | tail -n1 \
    | ( read line junk
        sed -e $line's/^/\n\n/' long-file > new-file
      )
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid perl :/

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker: Why?

Comment: Because I'm not good in Perl and try to keep the number of different scripting language I use as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/close unit 1/,$!b;/close unit 1/{x;/./p;x;h;d};H;$!d;x;i\line 1\nline 2\n...' file
```

Print every line before the first occurrence of `close unit 1` as normal. Store collections of lines beginning with `close unit 1` in the hold space and print the previous collection before storing the next. At the end of the file, the last collection will still be in the hold space, so insert the lines required and then print the last collection.